# Select from C# in sql server 2008 too slow in windows server 2003 :(

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I've a soft in C# connected it whith sql server 2008. There are some reports created by crystal report. When I execute my soft in windows XP and sql server is installed at the same windows it runs very fast it takes up to 3 seconds to select and fill report. But when I execute it in windows 2003 and sql server is installed in the same windows (I mean win 2003) it takes up to 40 seconds to execute the query and 2 second to fill the report. I unintalled and installed sql server 2008 twice but the same problem :(.

Why it is so slow ???????????????

Thnx

Comment: why haven't you posted enough information to answer your problem???????????????

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that the windows 2003 server is a better machine then your windows xp computer. How are you installing the database to the server? I'm guessing you are missing the indexes on server side.

If not, maybe you could post the sql statement that is executed.